# save multiple entities in Kinvey android

Tags: android, kinvey

Kinvey lets you save a single entity:

```
EventEntity event = new EventEntity();
//set data for event
myevents.save(event, new KinveyClientCallback<EventEntity>() {
    ....
});
```

But, I have an application where I need to save multiple(>20) entities at a time and don't want to make a call for each entity.

Kinvey provides this for iOS but not for android. Is there a way around this?

Considering that the entities are GenericJson, I was thinking there might be a way to combine the entities to get an array. As the backend would be the same for handling all the requests and as you can send multiple entities in iOS, it should handle an array if I manage to send one. But, how do I do that?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily fixed this by creating a Custom Endpoint and sending an array of entities to it.